# How to determine what upgrades to buy in Gun Bros?

Tags: gun-bros

I'm playing Gun Bros on my Android phone and I'm at level 13 with ~4300 coins. And I have no idea what upgrades I should get to make more progress.

Should I hoard coins until I can buy the more heavy guns at 10k+ coins or should I get one of the 3k ones? Because it would be easier to get more coins with a better weapon?

And what guns would probably be best for progressing as fast as possible? I can go for high DMG or high RPM, should I prefer one of the other at lower levels?

[image]

Comment: As long as you have a good damage gun, just collect money by going to haven. Once there, go to the sharp place located in the left top corner and there, no enemies will kill you from the side, unless you move to another place and attract zombies from the side. I suggest using the kracken for that, it's easy. Apocalypse is too slow. If you don't have a strong gun, just use what you can, and if you can't handle it, just run away while shooting.

Comment: What is Haven ?

Answer (score 1):

I always get the gun that has highest DMG*RPM I can afford. This way the damage you can  inflict per timeunit is as high as possible.

Comment: Do the range + spread have anything to with it as well? Or does this become less important once you get into bigger, better weapons?